# Is Google Analytics for Mobile still working?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

At my company we are making a new iOS + Android app.

We need to get screen views analytics.

At my company doesn't like Firebase Analytics because with the new events analytics (vs the old page views) marketing team can't get enought information from the new events reports.

So I was requested to implement this app analytics using the "old" Google Analytics for Mobile SDK (the one that was used before Firebase) using a Universal Analytics property.

In iOS seems to be working. At least I see myself as active user in Google Analytics. But it's not saving the screen paths.

In Android it doesn't even push the screen views to Google Analytics.

Does anyone knows if Google Analytics for Mobile with a universal analytics property can still be used in 2021?

Or I am obliged to use Firebase Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the historical hits data in Analytics Universal Mobile always seems to be accessible in Google Analytics. However Google sent an email to Analytics's users where it communicated that:

> We want to let you know that in October 2019 we will begin to sunset our Google Analytics for mobile apps reporting and the Google Analytics Services SDK. We are investing our resources in the latest style of app reporting in Google Analytics that works in conjunction with Firebase – Google’s integrated app developer platform. As such, the following will take place:
>
> In 2019, we will begin to decommission properties that receive data exclusively from the Google Analytics Services SDK.
> Data collection and processing for such properties will stop on October 31, 2019.
> Reporting access through our UI and API access will remain available for these properties’ historical data until January 31, 2020.
> After our service is fully turned down, these properties will no longer be accessible via our Google Analytics UI or API, and their data will be removed from Google Analytics servers. You will receive further notification when this time nears.
> At this time, no Analytics 360 properties are impacted by these changes.

Anyway Google want to focus on Firebase (GA4) as the new paradigm for Google’s mobile app (and web) analytics soit is appropriate to use the new data collection model and not the old SDK.